# X type variable (REDEFINGED AS digit, with 'SIGN IS TRAILING SEPARATE') changed after execute "IF xxx NUMERIC"

Tags: cobol, trailing

I'm working on opencoobol1.1, and I encountered the weird problem:

Here is the Cobol code:

```
03 WS-INP              PIC X(30).                     
03 WS-INP-D REDEFINES WS-INP.                         
   05 WS-AMT1  PIC S9(6)V99 SIGN IS TRAILING SEPARATE.


MOVE 'QQQQQQQQQQQQ' TO WS-INP
DISPLAY WS-INP                   
IF WS-AMT1 NOT NUMERIC       
   DISPLAY WS-AMT1 
END-IF
DISPLAY WS-INP
```

After the code executed, the value of WS-INP changed to 'QQQQQQQQQQ-Q'！ It's supported to be keep the same value : 'QQQQQQQQQQQQ'.

So, what's wrong with the code? I found out that it's the 'IF xxx NUMERIC' sentence , aka 'IF WS-AMT1 NOT NUMERIC', caused the problem, and the type of WS-AMT1 , aka ' SIGN IS TRAILING SEPARATE'.

If the type is not ' SIGN IS TRAILING SEPARATE', everything is ok. But what is wrong with the ' SIGN IS TRAILING SEPARATE' ?

After remove ' SIGN IS TRAILING SEPARATE', things goes works.

Comment: There is no such bug in IBM COBOL. It's may just a bug in open cobol. It may fixed by change the cobol config or upgrade to the newer version of cobol, but I don't know how do and not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that his statement changes the field contents:

```
IF WS-AMT1 NOT NUMERIC
```

Since WS-AMT1 is defined to be a signed number, when checking for a sign in the last value, this statement might cause the value of the last byte to be "normalized", which means that the first half-byte is set to x'C' (for positive). This will eventually cause weird character to appear when displaying the field as a valid number.

Note that this depends on how exactly the compiler works, and probably also on the compiler options used. I don't know opencobol, so I have to make assumptions.

I suppose you actually wanted to display the character field if the field is not numeric, perhaps like so

```
IF WS-AMT1 NOT NUMERIC       
   DISPLAY WS-INP
ELSE
   DISPLAY WS-INP 
END-IF
```

Comment: All I want  is that the 'WS-INP' not be changed after execute "IF xxx NUMERIC".

if  WS-INP is changed  after execute "IF xxx NUMERIC" ,  it doesn't make sense. I think it's a bug and I don't like this .

Can't you understand me ?

Comment: Can you show me a solution to fix this.  It's unacceptable.

Comment: @llx Just perform the test on a copy instead of the original value.

Comment: I found a workaround that " test on a copy instead of the original value" a few days ago , as you said.  For example: 
1 declare a variable WS-AMT2  the same as  WS-AMT1. 
2 move WS-AMT1 to WS-AMT2;  
3 test on WS-AMT2 instead of WS-AMT, aka IF WS-AMT2 NOT NUMERIC  ...;  

It works. But , I dont' like this workaround .

Comment: I've solved it by modify the source code of opencobol1.1 ,  that is a bug of it.